# The options "align_double_arrow", "align_equals" do not exist. Defined options are: "default", "operators"

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

In my php-cs-fixer.php I have this line:

```
'binary_operator_spaces' => ['align_equals' => false, 'align_double_arrow' => true],
```

And it is giving me an error saying:

```
The options "align_double_arrow", "align_equals" do not exist. Defined options are: "default", "operators".
```

Could you help with using `operators and default` to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [upgrade guide](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/3.0/UPGRADE-v3.md#changed-options) you should use `operators` to choose needed strategy for each operator.

So in your case config will look like following:

```
'binary_operator_spaces' => [
    'operators' => [
        '=' => 'no_space',
        '=>' => 'align',
    ]
]
```

For more information check doc for [binary_operator_spaces](https://cs.symfony.com/doc/rules/operator/binary_operator_spaces.html) rule.